# Sending a hashed byte array from an android device, to a server socket and storing it

Tags: java, android, sockets, hash, arrays

I am having a problem on the receiving end i.e. The Server. It is receiving data, and I am trying to store that data in a byte array. I am doing this in a while loop, but it never terminates and I can't figure out why.

Android snippet:

```
try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

        byte[] keyBytes = keystore.get("secretkey");
        byte[] nonceBytes = nonce.getBytes("UTF-8");

        outputStream.write( nonceBytes );
        outputStream.write( keyBytes );

        byte[] bytesToEncrypt = outputStream.toByteArray();

        byte[] hashedBytes = digest.digest(bytesToEncrypt);

        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(myserver, myport);
        OutputStream outToServer = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        outToServer.write(hashedBytes);
    }
```

Server snippet:

```
try {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8311);

    while(true) {
        Socket connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("Receivied something..");

        InputStream inFromClient = connectionSocket.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[connectionSocket.getReceiveBufferSize()];

        try {
            System.out.println("Trying to store data in byte array");
        int bytesRead = -1;

        while( ( bytesRead = inFromClient.read( buffer ) ) != -1 ) {  
            baos.write( buffer, 0, bytesRead );
        }

        // This never prints
        System.out.println("Done");


        challengeReceived = baos.toByteArray();
        } 
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

It will never print "Done" with this implementation. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server exits from the

```
    while( ( bytesRead = inFromClient.read( buffer ) ) != -1 ) {  
        baos.write( buffer, 0, bytesRead );
    }
```

loop when client closes the connection.

Try to close the connection from client side by using `close()` call. This way:

```
outToServer.write(hashedBytes);
clientSocket.close();
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that.. Thank you!!